# Prestashop store not display after installation

Tags: windows, prestashop, laragon

hello preparing a demo for someone,
I have followed the step to install a Prestashop locally on Laragon.
all was working well till the end of installation and installation folder removal.

now all the links are down and I got an error about the SSL certificate that says this website can't offer secure connexion. the answer sends by the website is wrong.

have you already encountered this kind of issue with Prestashop installation and how to get out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably chose to enable SSL during installation, while your local environment does not come with a trusted certificate.

Anyway you should be able to reach backoffice by trusting the browser alert and disable SSL support from "Advanced parameters" menu.

If not, go direcly in DB (**ps_configuration** table) and force disabling SSL by setting "**PS_SSL_ENABLED**" and "**PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE**" config keys to 0 value.

Comment: thanks for your help , since i use wamp instead of laragon for that , but if someone else encount this trouble , he can try the both solution too see

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this easily Enabling the SSL certificate built-in with Laragon.

Just right click on the (maybe hided) Laragon icon on the system tray (located at the bottom right in the Windows Taskbar) and then `-> Apache -> SSL -> Enabled` (be sure after the selection it will be checked then).

Then just click in the same way on `-> Apache -> Reload`, and then reload the page on the browser to see your https website version in locale.